# How to start reading a file x bytes from the beginning in Julia?

Tags: julia

I need to read records from a file, each being 9 bytes long. I need to know how to start reading at different points in the file

Comment: It needs to be shown what attempts you made, and what errors ( if any ) you got . [How-to-ask-a-good-question-StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you're looking for the `seek` function:

```
help?> seek
search: seek seekend seekstart ParseError setenv select select! selectperm

  seek(s, pos)

  Seek a stream to the given position.
```

In particular you might want to

```
open(filename) do f
    seek(f, n)  # seek past nth byte
    read(f, m)  # read m bytes
end
```

There is also the `skip` function that may come in useful

```
help?> skip
search: skip skipchars

  skip(s, offset)

  Seek a stream relative to the current position.
```