# How to read the last x bytes of a (binary) file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I’m learning Julia and I’m trying to read the last 128 bytes of a binary file, without reading all the file. I think I should somehow seek to 128 bytes from the end then read from there.

I’ve [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42266172/735926) the [`seek`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/index.html#Base.seek) function but it only allows me to use an offset from the start of the file. There’s the [`seekend`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/index.html#Base.seekend) function to go to the end of the file, but not `x` bytes before. There’s also [`skip`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/index.html#Base.skip) but, again, it only allows to go forward.

I’m afraid using `skip(f, size_of_my_file - 128)` on a large file would read `size_of_my_file - 128` bytes instead of jumping to that position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it: `seek` to the end of the file, and "skip" `-128` bytes:

```
content = open(filename) do f
  seekend(f)
  skip(f, -128)
  read(f, String) 
end
```

(thank you [@mbauman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176071/mbauman) for the negative `skip` trick!)

Comment: You can `skip` backwards — just use a negative value.  E.g., `skip(f, -128)` after seekend'ing.